# After I clone MASTER and create a BRANCH from MASTER, is it necessary to PUBLISH my branch to remote?

Tags: git, github

NOTE I am using GitHub Desktop. So I'm guessing the answer to my question depends on what I am trying to do after I create my branch. Well, all I want to do is;

1. change files
2. commit to branch
3. submit my pull request
4. merge to master
5. a SYNC... to make sure I have the latest code committed to master, before I start making more changes to commit (repeat at step 1).

My understand is 2,3,4,5 are required for Git. Am I missing something?
What is Publishing my branch supposed to do?

Comment: If this answered your question, would you please mark the checkmark beside it?

Answer (score 2):

Publishing makes it visible to the remote source, which is important because the owner of the repo is merging *something* into their `master`, and that *something* is your branch. It needs to be visible for that to happen.

Comment: Submitting a pull request appears to do a publish. I never touched the publish button. So that's why I asked; seems like there's no need to publish if I'm always going to submit pull requests when I'm ready for my changes to be merged. When would I ever commit to my branch, skip the pull request, and do a publish instead?

Comment: Good question. You'd do that if you want to collaborate with other people on your side branch.

Comment: I guess should just ignore the publish button then. We don't collaborate that way on my project.